# SQL Server Update with Join / Active Column

Tags: sql-server

I think this code is better to show, what i want to do:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.[Changed] = 1
FROM [dbo].[Table1] A
INNER JOIN [Table2] E
        ON [A].[Part] = [E].[ActivePart]

UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
    [Range] = [Range]
WHERE [Partgroup] = [Partgroup] AND [Changed] > 0
```

Before Update:

[image]

After Update:

[image]

Please help.

Thank you very much.

Greetz
Vegeta_77

Comment: First of all, I guess you mixed up A and E in several locations in your code... you seem to update the values with the value itself again. And furthermore in the WHERE: A.[Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1] <> A.[Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1] should NEVER be true... Could you please clarify which error you are experiencing after correcting the aliases?

Comment: Hi Rene. Do you mean, it have to be: ON E = A instead of E = A? There is no error, but the Statement is updating only 1 row instaed of all. The last row, whose Plan-Column was changed should be the lead-column for the update-Statement.

Comment: To be honest, I wonder why ANY row has been updated at all. See, you update table A with its own values (set a.[col1] = a.[col1]) ans then rerstrict the whole statement with an impossible comparison (WHERE a.[col2] <> a.[col2])... are you sure, that any row has been updated? I would have suggested something like "set a.col1 = e.col1 ... WHERE a.col2 = e.col2 AND a.col3 <> e.col3..."

Comment: So i edit my question. I hope you can understand my Problem better now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here is the solution:

```
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Range] = (SELECT [Range] 
               FROM [Table1] A
               INNER JOIN [Table2] E
                   ON [A].[Part] = [E].[ActivePart])
WHERE [Partgroup] = (SELECT [Partgroup] 
                     FROM [Table1] B
                     INNER JOIN [Table2] F
                         ON [B].[Part] = [F].[ActivePart])
```

Sometimes, I think to complicatet. Thx Rene.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first part looks better (even if I think the WHERE isn't needed, since it concerns the same column you are joining on). Nevertheless, the second update shouldn't produce any changes:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Superliste_000]
SET [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1] = [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1],
    [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl2] = [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl2],
    [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl3] = [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl3],
    [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl4] = [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl4]
WHERE [Teilegruppe] = [Teilegruppe] AND [Date_change] > 0
```

Again you update [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1] with [Plan-TGrp-Spanne_Stfl1] - which is the same value... Either I am too tired and misinterprete the code or there is another little bug in your update. ;-)